# What is/are the minimum sensor(s) is needed to get inclination/tilt/pitch of project with roll compesation?

Tags: sensor, compass

I am planning a project that will measure and log the tilt of my push bike while I am riding it. The fastest that I would be recording is every 0.1 seconds, though it will probably be every 1 second. I am planning on using an Arduino as the platform.

From my research, I am currently unsure whether I just need a magnetometer (2 axis?) or whether I need to add a gyroscope and accelerometer as well?

As I am not located very near either of the earth's poles (i.e., mainland Australia) and am not thinking on going particularly far, so calibration at the start may allow accurate measurements using a magnetometer. However, I am not sure that it can be used like that.

Comment: The [TI Chronos "Sports Watch"](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-chronos?DCMP=Chronos&HQS=Other%252BOT%252Bchronos)may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that even top spec Android phones and iPhones run magnetometers, gyros and accelerometers and still aren't that accurate, I would definitely recommend all.

Gyroscopes will give you the fastest response to tilting. Accelerometers will give you the fastest response to a linear movement.

Comment: I thought most high end phones have one acceleration or gyroscope and a compass unit. I did not think they carried multiple. If you have a nice gyroscope and a nice accelerometer you can tell your location, but both are needed and rarely included.

Comment: iPhone has gyros, accelerometers and magnetometer. I think the top end htc phones have gyros too

Comment: http://www.tested.com/news/how-iphone-4s-gyroscope-sets-new-standard-for-mobile-motion/393/

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize how decked out the phones are.